# Referencing View model in web api .NET

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on web api in .NET. Basically I wanted to know if it is valid for a web api to accept a an domain class but then reference a view model in the api controller.

I personally feel this would not be correct as domain classes should only be accepted as the web api should not know anything about the View model class?

An example of the code is below:

I have used the approach of thin controllers and therefore have implemented an execute method which would do all the processing, in the case below it would add to the repository.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(Staff staffMember)
    {
        command.Execute(new StaffVM { Staff = staffMember }, ModelState);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, staffMember.name);            
    }
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: you never use staffMember in your example (should it be Staff = staffMember? - but then StaffVM is just a wrapper class?)

Comment: Have edited sorry changed the object names as did not want to show real names.

Comment: I think really i just wanted to clarify if it is valid to use the view model within an api controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the API Put method receives a put request the default model binder will attempt to map the incoming requests properties to those in the model. If re-using an MVC controllers Model fits the mapping request then I think this is an acceptable approach.

The only consideration here is that *right now* the requirements of the Api Put method and the  other Controller method that uses `Staff` are aligned, but if the requirement for the original controller changes so that the model changes, you might break the API method and the mapping might fail.

On the other hand, if in the future the needs of the API Controller mean that the `Staff` model can no longer be used you can just replace the API method signature appropriately.